# Linear equality in two variables equivalent to region below line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm studying high school algebra and we were posed this question:

> Lester thinks that the solution of any inequality with a > sign is the
>   region above the line and the solution of any inequality with a < sign
>   is the region below the line. Is Lester correct? Explain why or why
>   not.

Is this true? Or if it's not, can you please give me a counterexample?

Comment: An inequality $a > b$ can simply be written as $b < a$ or $-a < -b$.

Answer (score 2):

To be fair, you were given a *very* confusing question. "Any inequality" is clearly not even what your teacher meant, if this question is about linear inequalities in two variables. Did they mean any inequality of the form
$$ax + by + c < 0$$
for real numbers $a,b,c$?

It's true that
$$ax+by+c=0$$
is the equation of a line in the plane (in standard form) and that this line must partition the plane into a half-space where $ax+by+c$ is positive, and one where the expression is negative (since the value of $ax+by+c$ changes smoothly and is only zero when you touch the line). How can we tell whether the "top" or "bottom" half-space is the negative one? We can plug in a test point $(0,Y)$:
$$bY + c$$
and test what happens when $Y\to -\infty$: if $b>0$, the first term becomes more and more negative (while $c$ stays the same) so $bY+c$ is negative for sufficiently large $Y$; similarly when $b<0$ the expression becomes more and more positive.

So we can conclude that
$$ax+by+c < 0$$
describes a region below a line when $b>0$ and above a line when $b<0$ (when $b=0$ the line is vertical and "below" doesn't even make any sense.)